# Is there a Google Drive API share callback like for file picker

Tags: google-drive-api

In order to further integrate my app with Google Drive I added the Google Drive sharing dialog as explained here https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app It gives the same dialog as in Drive itself which is great. What I miss is the option of a callback function like the Drive file-picker has to process the result of the sharing dialog. Does anyone know any further documentation on this, I have only found this specific example.

Comment: Honestly, I don't exactly get what you mean or the problem. Can you please elaborate further what you mean with "process the result of the sharing dialog"?

Comment: The simplest result is a callback when you close the sharing dialog. The filepicker dialog also gives the file(s) you actually picked, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#callback-types.

Comment: @Teyam Filepicker api has a method called .setCallback, sharing dialog doesn't as far as I can tell.